# Linear regression in very unbalanced data

Tags: r, regression, unbalanced-classes, stratification, subsampling

I hope you can help me with this question. I have a dataset with several classes (around 25) and they are very unbalanced. Some classes have thousands of subjects, others hundreds, and others just a few subjects. I want to see the association between brain measures from each subject and their class, and for this I'm using linear regression in R, using the function lm().

I first thought the best approach would be to do stratified sampling, making subsamples selecting up to 5 subjects in each class and repeat this process 1000 times. Then, do the statistics on each subs-sample. I would like to know what to do, after generating the coefficients and p-values for 1000 sub-samples, in order to have a final p-value that tells me if there is a real association between brain measures and those classes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a mixed model?  Stratified sampling will obfuscate the natural frequencies of the classes in the population (assuming the sizes of your sample reflect the sizes in the population accurately).  With a mixed model, you can naturally model the variation between classes and pool estimates for classes with fewer observations closer to the grand mean (which is a good thing for various reasons I won't get into now).

You can do this very easily with the `lme4` package and `lmer` function.  Do you have a sample of your data we can play with?  Doesn't have to be your data, but a reasonable facsimile could allow me to demonstrate the advantages.

Comment: Hi @Demetri. Thank you for your answer. I have used lmer function before, in another context, but I'm not sure how to apply it here. So, I have a dataset with thousands of controls and then subjects with different genetic variations. Some variations have more subjects than others, and yes in most part they reflect what happens in general population, with the exception of one rare variation where we have more because of a particular study.

Comment: I'm not sure how to share a sample with you here, but if it helps I'm interested in correlating brain measures, from different regions, with a value that is attributed to each of these variants, that reflects a certain risk. If we call this value "x", the brain measure "b" and the genetic variant "g", how would we compute this with lmer?

Comment: Just to add, that I would also like to add age and sex as covariates to the model.